# Example of $F\in W_0^{1,2}$ a.s. so that the law of $F+B$ is equivalent to that of $B$ but DD exponential isn't integrable?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Is there an explicit example of progressively measurable $F=\int_0^\cdot f(s) ds\in W_0^{1,2}(0,1)$ a.s. so that the law of $F+B$ on $(0,1)$ is equivalent to that of a Brownian motion $B$ on $(0,1)$ but the Doleans-Dade exponential $$\exp\left(\int_0^1f(s) dB(s)-\frac12\int_0^1f^2(s)ds\right)$$
is not integrable?